# Find difference (subtraction) for each variable in dataset by group

Tags: r, date, dataframe, data.table, plyr

I have a dataset with about 20 variables. Data was collected over three years (2012-2014) and for each year each observation can be grouped by `Site` and `Plot`.

I would like to find the difference (i.e. change in value) for each observation between years. Since I started data collection in 2012 I would like to find the difference between 2013 and 2012, and 2014 and 2013 (2014 - 2012, would also be welcomed).

First, I've made some attempts with both `plyr` and `data.table` trying to find the difference between years for just one variable. These have been unsuccessful. I am unsure on how to call an operation to subtract by `Year` while grouping by `Site` and `Plot`. Moreover, I am not sure where to store it.

I have included a sample data set with just 3 variables. I have also included a sample desired output (`output`), however, the formatting isn't crucial. I am more interested in the values.

If `ddply` or `data.table` seem like good options, I'd appreciate some suggestions. If they appear to be the wrong tools for the job, I'd appreciate that information as well. While not included here, the full date (YYYY-mm-dd) could be included in the dataset. All `Plot`s within a `Site` were observed on the same day and month for a given year.

```
require(plyr)
require(data.table)
# df data.frame
df <- structure(list(Site = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 
3.2), Plot = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
    Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
    2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L), V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L), VH1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, NA, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), V2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L)), .Names = c("Site", "Plot", "Year", 
"V1", "VH1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")

# as data.table
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# ddply attempt for just one variable: V1
ans.d <- ddply(df, .(Year, Site, Plot), transform, V1.1213=c(NA,diff(V1)))

# data.table attempt for just one variable: V1
KEY <- c("Year", "Site", "Plot")
setkeyv(dt, KEY)
ans.dt <- dt[,diff:=c(NA,diff(V1)),by=KEY]    
ans.dt1 <- dt[, c('V1.1','V1.1213') := list(V1[1], V1 - V1[1]),by = KEY]

# data table attempt with diff key
KEY2 <- c("Site", "Plot")
setkeyv(dt, KEY2)
ans.dt.k2 <- dt[,diff:=c(NA,diff(V1)),by=Year] 

# example solution
# where V1.1213 is [(V1, Year = 2013) - (V1, Year = 2012)], etc.
output <- structure(list(Site = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 
3.2), Plot = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
    Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
    2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L), V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L), VH1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, NA, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), V2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), V1.1213 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V1.1314 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), VH1.1213 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), VH1.1314 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 6L, 6L, NA, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), V2.1213 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, -3L, 
    NA, -3L, -3L, -3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2.1314 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L)), .Names = c("Site", 
"Plot", "Year", "V1", "VH1", "V2", "V1.1213", "V1.1314", "VH1.1213", 
"VH1.1314", "V2.1213", "V2.1314"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)    
fun <- funs(
  lag1 = .-lag(., order_by = Year, n = 1), 
  lag2 = .-lag(., order_by = Year, n = 2)
)
df %>% 
  group_by(Site, Plot) %>% 
  mutate_each(fun, -Year)
```

Some explanation:

- `mutate_each` applies the function(s) specifed in the argument "funs()" to the variable specified in the last argument. When the input data.frame is grouped (using `group_by`), it applies the function within each group.
- The argument `funs(.-lag(., order_by = Year, n = 2))` specifies the function to apply to each column. You can see other specification in `?funs`. You can specify multiple functions in funs ; you can also specifies new suffixes.

  The function `lag` in `dplyr` (see ?lag) allows to lag a vector. `lag` had two options. The first, `order_by`, reorders the variable specified in `order_by` if needed. The second, `n` specifies the number of  periods you want to lag. For instance

  ```
  lag(c(1,2,3))
  lag(c(1,2,3), order_by = c(2, 1, 3), n = 1)
  ```

  I wrote `order_by = Year`, but it is not needed if the dataset is already ordered (as in the example).
- The last argument, `-Year,` applies the functions to all the variables except Year. See `?select`.

Comment: Should your solution begin with `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: The above will give the answer for Year 2014-2012. Is it possible to do it for the differences requested above?  If possible, an explanation of this line of code `mutate_each(funs(.-lag(., order_by = Year, n = 2)), -Year)` would be helpful, first time using `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

Smth like this?

```
cols = c('V1', 'VH1', 'V2')
dt[, paste0(cols, 'diff') := lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA, diff(x))),
     by = list(Site, Plot), .SDcols = cols][]
#    Site Plot Year V1 VH1 V2 V1diff VH1diff V2diff
# 1:  1.0    1 2012  1   2  3     NA      NA     NA
# 2:  1.0    2 2012  1   2  3     NA      NA     NA
# 3:  2.0    1 2012  1   2  3     NA      NA     NA
# 4:  2.0    2 2012  1   2  3     NA      NA     NA
# 5:  2.0    3 2012  1   2  3     NA      NA     NA
# 6:  3.2    1 2012  1   2 NA     NA      NA     NA
# 7:  3.2    2 2012  1   2  3     NA      NA     NA
# 8:  3.2    3 2012  1   2  3     NA      NA     NA
# 9:  3.2    4 2012  1   2  3     NA      NA     NA
#10:  1.0    1 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     -3
#11:  1.0    2 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     -3
#12:  2.0    1 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     -3
#13:  2.0    2 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     -3
#14:  2.0    3 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     -3
#15:  3.2    1 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     NA
#16:  3.2    2 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     -3
#17:  3.2    3 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     -3
#18:  3.2    4 2013  0   4  0     -1       2     -3
#19:  1.0    1 2014  5  10 20      5       6     20
#20:  1.0    2 2014  5  10 20      5       6     20
#21:  2.0    1 2014  5  NA 20      5      NA     20
#22:  2.0    2 2014  5  10 20      5       6     20
#23:  2.0    3 2014  5  10 20      5       6     20
#24:  3.2    1 2014  5  10 20      5       6     20
#25:  3.2    2 2014  5  10 20      5       6     20
#26:  3.2    3 2014  5  10 20      5       6     20
#27:  3.2    4 2014  5  10 20      5       6     20
#    Site Plot Year V1 VH1 V2 V1diff VH1diff V2diff
```